# How to install BaseOS.repo in CentOS 8

Tags: linux, redhat, rhel7, centos8, rhel8

Version: Linux version 4.18.0-305.10.2.el8_4.x86_64 (mockbuild@x86-vm-09.build.eng.bos.redhat.com) (gcc version 8.4.1 20200928 (Red Hat 8.4.1-1) (GCC))

I am trying to install 'yum-utils' but I am getting an error:
Unable to find a match: 'yum-utils'
After bit of a research I realized that it requires BaseOS.repo file for its installation.

Output after running command 'dnf repolist':

| repo id | repo name |
| --- | --- |
| epel | Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 8 - x86_64 |
| pgAdmin4 | pgadmin4 |
| pgdg-common | PostgreSQL common RPMs for RHEL/CentOS 8 - x86_64 |
| pgdg12 | PostgreSQL 12 for RHEL/CentOS 8 - x86_64 |
| pgdg13 | PostgreSQL 13 for RHEL/CentOS 8 - x86_64 |

As you can see BaseOS.repo is missing in this list.

One more thing to note is the fact that CentOS Linux 8 (EndOfLife: 2021-12-31) is already outdated. Could that be an issue?

Comment: `subscription-manager repos --enable=rhel-8-for-x86_64-baseos-rhui-rpms --enable=rhel-8-for-x86_64-appstream-rhui-rpms`

Comment: @GoinOff This system is not subscribed.

Comment: Yeah, that was my other thought on the problem.. All good now